# How to create dynamic menu with sub option

Tags: android, android-layout, android-menu

How to create a dynamic menu or using layout. If i click on image then open one menu in this menu if i click on option then another menu open like sub menu :

please find below image to batter understanding :

[image]

Comment: Please add the code you wrote so far